# Attached zip file, created by Excel VBA, is open when attempting to send

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to send an email with an attachment.

I create a ZIP folder with the following code:

```vb
Sub ZipFolder(folderToZipPath As Variant, zippedFileFullName As Variant)

    Dim ShellApp As Object
    
    'Create an empty zip file
    Open zippedFileFullName For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
    
    'Copy the files & folders into the zip file
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(folderToZipPath).items
    
    'Zipping the files may take a while, create loop to pause the macro until zipping has finished.
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items.Count = ShellApp.Namespace(folderToZipPath).items.Count
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```

With the following I get the message from Outlook that the attachment is still open. I have to confirm this manually before it sends the email.

Can it be that the ZIP folder created by the macro was not closed?

```
' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objEmail
        .to = xxx
        .cc = xxx"
        .Subject = "subject"
        .Body = "body"
        .Display
        .Attachments.Add (Path & PDF)
        .Attachments.Add (Path & zip)
        .Send
    End With
```

Comment: Try `Set ShellApp = Nothing`  in your `ZipFolder` procedure after zipping of the file is done.

Comment: This didn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the file lock status instead 1 second delay per item:

```
Option Explicit

Sub WaitForFreeFile()
    Dim path As String, counter As Integer
    path = "c:\Users\Alex20\Documents\emptyZIP.zip"
    
    ' the process of copying a 100 MB file into a .zip has started
    
    Do While isLocked(path)
        If counter = 0 Then Debug.Print "File is locked @ " & Now   'debugging info
        counter = counter + 1                                       'debugging info
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        Debug.Print "Check file status # " & counter & " @ " & Now  'debugging info
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Debug.Print "The file has been released @ " & Now
    
    ' your code
End Sub

Function isLocked(fullpath As String)
    Dim ff As Integer
    ff = FreeFile
    On Error Resume Next
    Open fullpath For Input Lock Read As #ff
    isLocked = Err.Number <> 0
    Close #ff
End Function
```

**Output**

```
File is locked @ 31.05.2021 15:02:16
Check file status # 1 @ 31.05.2021 15:02:17
Check file status # 2 @ 31.05.2021 15:02:18
Check file status # 3 @ 31.05.2021 15:02:19
Check file status # 4 @ 31.05.2021 15:02:20
Check file status # 5 @ 31.05.2021 15:02:21
The file has been released @ 31.05.2021 15:02:21
```

Also note that `Do Until ...items.Count = ....items.Count` may will not finish if some of items will not copied (e.g. empty folders) and first .Count will never equal second .Count.

Comment: Hello, neither of the solutions leads to success, unfortunately. The zip directory is not locked, I tested it with the function. Even if I want to attach the directory after a restart, Outlook issues the same warning as described above. It says something like this: "The attachment "xxx" opened from the message"xxx" is open or used by another application". If you continue the process, your changes from the attachment will be lost. Do you want to continue the operation?" (translated, so not exactly as in English).